# How to correct the delay occuring to a countdown timer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, settimeout, countdown

I've a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FvYyS/3/)

In this fiddle the count down timer is running but it's lagging behind in time. Can anyone please correct this issue of time lag behind in the fiddle?

Also when the timer reaches the value `00:04:59` it starts blinking. Now every thing is blinking including the labels, timer hr, min, sec values, the colons in between. I want to blink only the min and sec digits when timer reaches to `00:04:59` but the red font-color which is applying now should be the same for all the elements. No change in font-color.

Comment: there is good information,  on how timer works in http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: lag in time cannot be taken care of .. which is also suggeset by the above link

Comment: The fiddle here is now deleted, which is why we ask that code is added to questions as well as on external paste boards. This will, unfortunately, need to be put on hold. If you can add a new paste link and/or repair the question, that would be ideal.

Comment: Closure guideline: "Questions seeking debugging help ... must include ... the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was because a timeFlag variable:

```
  if(timeFlag == 0) {
    secs--; 
    timeFlag++;
  } else {
    timeFlag--;
  }
```

this means that the code `secs--;` was executed only once in 2 seconds.

Correction:
http://jsfiddle.net/artur99/FvYyS/17/

Answer (score 1):

I have changed code for blinking the min and sec digits alone

Try this code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/JRehn/3)**

```
  if( hrs <= 0 && mins <= 4)
  {
     document.getElementById('list').style.color="red";
  }
  else
  {
      document.getElementById('list').style.color="black";
      styleFlag = 1;  
  }
  if(styleFlag == 0) {
     styleFlag = 1;  
     document.getElementById('hr').innerHTML = hours;
     document.getElementById('mins').innerHTML = "";
     document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML = "";
  }    
  else
  {
      styleFlag = 0; 
      document.getElementById('hr').innerHTML = hours;
      document.getElementById('mins').innerHTML = minutes;
      document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML = seconds;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's working for me but how to fix the issue of time lag?